# Azure Functions: Multiple developers building Functions on Same Azure Function APP

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio, function

We do not have Azure DevOps or GIT enabled currently. We are using Azure Functions plugin to deploy Functions to Azure, via Visual Code. Note, we also have some data files folders and other shared code folders.

Was trying to determine the best way two developers could work on two different functions within the same Function App, with their individual deployments not replacing each others Functions. I do not see a way in Visual Code to deploy just one specific Function, it deploys the whole Function App.

Comment: you definitely need to have CI/CD pipeline either through azure devops or github actions

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use something like Git to track changes across different functions within the same function app across different developers. If you are deploying functions hoping to not overwrite the function app because you want to test things, then it might be better to just do it locally first and then have the final version go to the function app on azure.